# Can I disable a cookie from a contrib module, in this case fontawesome I believe

Tags: 8, cookies

I have a D8 site v8.9.6 and have some questions on cookies.

I would prefer not to have any cookies on my site unless they are really required for a properly functioning website. With all things going on like GDPR and APP I prefer to have this as clean as possible.

In order to find out which cookies are in use I checked Chrome DevTools and it shows me just 1: _ga with source of fontawesome.com (I installed the FontAwesome module).
First question, can I disable this cookie somehow?

Second question is related to [Dropdown Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropdown_language), a module that gives me a dropdown select list for the user to select its language of choice. I can't find anything in the documentation about how this tracks the user's choice and I don't see anything in DevTools (cookies, session), so this is not working with cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Font Awesome Icons module provides an option to use the Font Awesome library locally rather than from a CDN. It's the CDN that is creating the tracking cookie, so if you follow the instructions to download Font Awesome to your own server, you should not have that cookie to worry about.

The Dropdown Language module simply extends Drupal's built-in language switching, which defaults to storing the language in the current session, so will not require any additional cookies.